# Remove nested lists where all elements are None

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a series of lists (within a dictionary) and I would like to remove any which only have `None` as elements. However, the lists have various different formattings e.g.

```
x=[None,[None],[None]]
x=[None,None,None]
x=[None,[None,None],[None,None]]
```

where any `None` could be replaced with a value.

Any example would be the following dictionary:

```
dict={"x1": [None,None,None],"x2": [None,[None],[None]], "x3": [None,[1],[0.5]],
      "x4":[None,[None,None],[None,None]],"x5":[None,[180,-360],[90,-180]]}
```

In this case I would like to keep `(key,value)` pairs `"x3"` and `"x5"` as they contain values that are not all `None`, but would like to remove `"x1"`, `"x2"`, and `"x4"` thus returning:

```
dict={"x3": [None,[1],[0.5]], "x5":[None,[180,-360],[90,-180]]}
```

A simple list comprehension on the various lists (`x`) in the dictionary such as

```
any(e is not None for e in x)
```

reads `[None]` entries as `not None` and returns `True`.

How can I determine which lists actually contain a value rather than `[None]` elements. I have looked at options for removing the square brackets, e.g. using `itertools` such as suggested here [[Remove brackets from list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906322/remove-brackets-from-list-in-python) ], but these all rely on all the elements in the list being formatted in the same way, whereas I have mixed formatting. I am unable to change the formatting as it is required in this format elsewhere in the software.

Comment: Can you add expected outputs for more test cases? For example, what would be the output for `x=[None,[None,None],[None,None,1]]`?

Comment: I think they are saying that they have a dictionary: `d = {"x1": [None,[None],[None]], "x2": [None,None,None], "x3": [None,[None,None],[None,None]]}`, and wants to remove items where the list is entirely None, which would return an empty dict in their example. Essentially needs a function which will return True/False for whether all nested lists contain exclusively None values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a custom recursive function to check if all the elements of the nested list are `None` or not.

```
def is_none(a):
    return all(x is None if not isinstance(x, list) else is_none(x) for x in a)

my_dict = {"x1": [None, None, None],
           "x2": [None, [None], [None]],
           "x3": [None, [1], [0.5]],
           "x4": [None, [None, None], [None, None]],
           "x5": [None, [180, -360], [90, -180]]}

new_dict = {k: v for k, v in my_dict.items() if not is_none(v)}
print(new_dict)
# {'x3': [None, [1], [0.5]], 'x5': [None, [180, -360], [90, -180]]}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the comment of Benjamin, this function should return True if all the nested list in `list_input` contains the same value `val_to_check` and False otherwise:

```
def check_val(list_input, val_to_check):
    for elem in list_input:
        if isinstance(elem, list):
            if check_val(elem, val_to_check) == False:
                return False
        else:
            if elem != val_to_check:
                return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is similar in nature to that of Keyur Potdar, but it works for all kinds of containers, not only `list`:

```
my_dict = {
    "x1": [None, None, None],
    "x2": [None, [None], [None]],
    "x3": [None, [1], [0.5]],
    "x4": [None, [None, None], [None, None]],
    "x5": [None, [180, -360], [90, -180]],
}

def all_None(val):
    # Check for None
    if val is None:
        return True
    # val is not None
    try:
        # val may be a container
        return all(all_None(el) for el in val)
    except:
        # val is neither None nor a container
        return False

my_dict_filtered = {key: val for key, val in my_dict.items() if not all_None(val)}
print(my_dict_filtered)
```